# block height is an issue - i tried all ways but :(

Tags: html, css

having trouble with post height. help me guys..

[image]

please check the website : http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/

```
<li>
<div class="thumb-img">
<a title="Hiring a Professional Designer for Your Kitchen" href="http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/hiring-a-professional-designer-for-your-kitchen/">
<img class="attachment-home-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="163" height="110" title="Oak kitchen Cupboard" alt="Oak kitchen Cupboard" src="http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/uploads/Oakkitchen31-163x110.png">
</a>
</div>
<div class="post-text">
<h3>
<a href="http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/hiring-a-professional-designer-for-your-kitchen/">Hiring a Professional Designer for Your Kitchen</a>
</h3>
<p>
Ensuring that you hire the correct professional is far more important than vision, design or budget when it comes to having your kitchen built properly and safely.
<a class="more-link" href="http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/hiring-a-professional-designer-for-your-kitchen/#more-580">
<span class="more">[more]</span>
</a>
</p>
<div class="wpfblike" style="height: 40px; display: none;">
<fb:like class=" fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" send="false" colorscheme="light" action="like" width="400" show_faces="true" layout="default" href="http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/hiring-a-professional-designer-for-your-kitchen/">
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: What do you want us to help you with?

Comment: i uploaded the image and also the url of the website .. on the main page of the website ... u will able to see 3 random post. these random posts are giving me height issue .. when i refrest the page some low words post comes up and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `border-bottom` in your `li` instead of `.post-text`. Write like this:

```
#homepage-images ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 560px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.post-text {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the image floating in the left-side... he could also add a "min-height" to the post-text to resolve...

Answer (score 1):

(1) Before each `</li>`, put a `div` for clearing. This is the most important step:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

(2) Move the `border-bottom` style from the post-text `div` to the `li`

(3) You can also add some `margin-bottom` to the `li` and reduce the `margin-bottom` of the `post-text`

Comment: If you don't want to bother adding the "clear fix" div, you can generally solve this by adding `overflow: hidden` to the containing element. In this case, move the border-bottom to the li, as described, but then just add `overflow: hidden` to the li, too. Setting `overflow` will make the container wrap the contained floating elements properly. Although even this relatively new method is starting to look a bit elderly now; see http://fordinteractive.com/2009/12/goodbye-overflow-clearing-hack/ for a good starting point for finding articles on various clear fix methods and their drawbacks.

Comment: @Matt Gibson: quotes from the article you linked: `I’m now saying goodbye to overflow: hidden` and `I’ll be abandoning overflow and relying upon clearfix` - in the OP case, `overflow: hidden` is useless - he does not want to avoid the height to increase, he wants to deal with a **too short paragraph**, when its border crosses the left-floated image (just look the image he posted)...

Comment: never saw `overflow: hidden` to clear fix; it was unknown to me... IMO, very counter-intuitive... seems more like a bug! isn't it supposed to hide stuff when the contents are bigger than a given fixed height?

Comment: Funny. Found an article suggesting `inline-block` over both the `clear` and `overflow` alternatives - this is what the OP is using, although no one answered it. The article: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/

Answer (score -2):

Set the margins and border of li tags instead of div tag.